# Python: Code errors out on different elements in response from URL

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

Techies,

I have a python script that uses the requests library to get/capture the JSON responses back from a 3rd party API. The code I have expects the element lanIp. In most cases, the element is there, however, it is possible for the element to not exist and for other elements to exist instead. Basically I have two valid possibilities for the result set. How do I manage this? I see that under the requests.exceptions there's a concept of invalid schemas and missing schemas. Should I use the jsonschema library; create 2 separate schemas then on exception for invalid schema retry with the second schema (as shown in code) or does anyone have any more eloquent suggestions?

```
  import jsonschema 
  from jsonschema import validate

  try:
   validate(responseDataJson, schemaA)            
   print 'version 1 json'
  except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
   print 'probably version 2 json'
   try:
    validate(responseDataJson, schemaB)
    print 'version 2 json'
  except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
    print 'really a bad version'
```